# Customise colour in IIF expression SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I currently have 2 values in one field: the total project count and the active projects count. The values are displayed as, for example, 100/50 on the data label within the pie chart.

Is it possible to format the colours of each value individually so that the "100" (total projects) for example is coloured black and the "50" (active projects) is coloured blue?

```
=Fields!TotalProjs.Value & "/" & Fields!ActiveProjs.Value
```

I can see an expression field for colour under the data labels but I'm unsure of the type of expression required in this case.

I've tried :

```
=IIF(fields!totalprojs.value>0,"black","red") & IIF(fields!activeprojs.value>0,"blue","red")
```

But I know this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using PlaceHolders.  It is illustrated in this article on Social.Microsoft site:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18748.ssrs-multi-font-color-multi-font-size-within-a-single-field-textbox.aspx

Comment: Is it possible to use placeholders on pie chart labels?

Answer (score 0):

**No** - unfortunately, there's not a way to color parts of a label's text separately.

The Label's COLOR property will only let one value be selected. You can't use placeholders in a label nor can you use HTML.

I can't think of any other workaround that can emulate anything like what you want.

Maybe put the values in a table below or next to your pie that emulates a Legend and includes the values? Then you could use either a placeholder or HTML for the color. IMHO - the HTML would be simpler to implement than placeholders since there would just be one expression with both values and both colors.